# What's wrong with this Query?

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with this SQL Query? I'm newbie

```
ALTER TABLE `users`;
ADD COLUMN `balance` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT '0.00' ;
```

Comment: `;` is a statement _terminator_ but all of this belongs in _one statement_ so it goes at the end.  Look over [the MySQL `ALTER TABLE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this without using the `;` before the `users` table:-

```
 ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `balance` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0.00;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this (remove the first semicolon, and the quotes around the default value):

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `balance` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0.00;
```